# Not able to connect to Microsoft Azure Mysql Database after deploying in Microsoft Azure

Tags: java, mysql, azure, jdbc

I am trying to connect Azure mysql database.  If I use application for local server (Eclipse) it is connecting to Azure MySql Database, once the application is deployed in azure hosting database string is not working.

```
//connecting to Azure MySql Database from local Application(Eclipse)
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://Hostname:Port/databasename", "username", "password");

//connecting to Azure MySql Database After Deploying Application in Azure(Microsoft Azure)
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://Hostname:Port;DatabaseName=databasename;","username","password");
```

Can anyone tell me how to write connecting String for Hosting Application?

Comment: Which option of MySQL on Azure did you use? ClearDB or MySQL in-app? Why there is the SQL Server jdbc connection code? Please improve your description for clarifying your question.

Comment: ClearDB. i got some documentation in that SQL Server jdbc connection code is there.so iam trying With that